# Extending a class of a node_module (Discord.Js <Client>). Error: Cannot find module './@types'

Tags: typescript, discord.js

I'm fairly new to TypeScript and I wanted to learn the language while creating a very simple Discord Bot, utilizing a module called [Discord.JS](https://discord.js.org/#/).
My problem is that I want to extend their [Client](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client) class and add my own methods and objects to store things in memory in a class called **myClient**

My directory tree (excluding /dist)

```
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── src
│   ├── bot.ts
│   ├── commands
│   │   └── test.ts
│   └── @types
│       └── index.d.ts
└── tsconfig.json
```

**@types/index.d.ts**

```
import { Client, Message, PermissionString, TextChannel, VoiceConnection, Collection, ClientOptions } from "discord.js";

export type ApplicationCommandOptionChoice = {
  readonly name: String;
  readonly value: String | number;
}

export type ApplicationCommandOption = {
  readonly type: number;
  readonly name: String;
  readonly description: String;
  readonly required?: Boolean;
  readonly choices?: Array<ApplicationCommandOptionChoice>;
  readonly options?: Array<ApplicationCommandOption>;

}

export interface ApplicationCommandModule<object> {
  readonly name: String;
  readonly description: String;
  readonly options?: Array<ApplicationCommandOption>;
  readonly default_permission?: Boolean;
  readonly permissions: PermissionString = 'SEND_MESSAGES';
  readonly usage: String;
  readonly devOnly?: Boolean;
  readonly execute: (args?: Array<T>) => any;
}

export class myClient extends Client {
  constructor(options: ClientOptions) {
    super(options);
    this.commands = new Collection();
  }
  public commands: Collection<String, object>;
  

  lookupCommand(name: String) {
    const command = this.commands.get(name);
    if (command) return command as ApplicationCommandModule<object>;
    return null;
  }

  executeCommand(name: String, ...args: any[]) {
    const command = this.commands.get(name);
    if (command) return (command as ApplicationCommandModule<object>).execute(args);
    return null;
  }
}
```

**bot.ts**

```
import Discord from 'discord.js';
import { myClient }  from './@types';

const client = new myClient({ intents: Discord.Intents.NON_PRIVILEGED });
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "strict": true,
    "types": ["./src/@types"],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  }
}
```

When I run **npm run dev** which is `ts-node-dev --respawn ./src/bot.ts` I get the following error:
[image]

**HOWEVER**, if I move the `export class myClient extends Client { ... }` code snippet from **index.d.ts** to **bot.ts** it works. That's confusing to me as I don't want to have my class in there.

So how do I go about importing `myClient` class properly? Also, why is it auto importing from @types, shouldn't this be "known"?

**Update:** I moved my `myClient` class in a .ts file called **client.ts** and imported that and it works. Why is that behavior? Can classes only be in .ts files? When I check node_modules their class extensions are in index.d.ts but not their methods. So if I put my class structure in index.d.ts where am I supposed to put its methods?

Comment: Just to fill in, I tried casting in my custom object like (client as any).myObject to avoid the above hassle but that doesn't give me any types and auto-completion so I want to refrain from doing it.

Comment: are you sure that discord.js is compatible with typescript?

Comment: `.d.ts` files are not supposed to hold logic, only types. Extend the class in a `.ts` file, and put the base types in the `.d.ts` file. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html

Comment: @AnžePintar Yes it is.

Comment: @Lioness100 Oh that explains it, thank you. Yeah moving it to a .ts file worked, i'll follow the link to make sure I did it right.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the way I did it is the best but here is how I solved my problem. Also mentioned by **Lioness100** in the comments.

Created a **client.ts** file and put my class in there

```
import { Client, ClientOptions, Collection } from "discord.js";
import { ApplicationCommandModule } from "./@types";

export default class myClient extends Client {
  public commands: Collection<String, ApplicationCommandModule>;
  public cooldowns: Collection<String, Collection<String, number>>;

  constructor(options: ClientOptions) {
    super(options);
    this.commands = new Collection();
    this.cooldowns = new Collection();
    this.loadCommads();
  }
  
  private loadCommads():void {
    const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(`${__dirname}/commands`).filter((file) => file.endsWith('.js') || file.endsWith('.ts'));
    commandFiles.forEach((file) => {
      const command = require(`${__dirname}/commands/${file}`);
      this.commands.set(command.default.name, (command.default as ApplicationCommandModule));
    });
  }
}
```

Imported it in **bot.ts** with `import myClient from './client'` and now I can access myClient with its properties and methods. It isn't the best practice to store commands and their cooldowns in there but I'm experimenting with TS.

If there is something wrong with this implementation please do edit or comment.

Comment: `.d.ts` files are usually only used in pair with `declare module '...'`. if you're not trying to augment/create types for an npm module, but instead trying to export interfaces, types, and classes relating only to your project, it should probably go in a regular `.ts` files. I personally like having a `interfaces` folder with one interface per file, such as `ApplicationCommandModule.ts`. Some people like putting every interface in one `.ts` file, and some like to put it in the file it relates to (not separating it from logic). However you want to do it, I don't think it should be with `.d.ts`

Comment: @Lioness100 I see. I read into it after reading your comment and I think I'm getting the hang of it. I checked some TypeScript projects on GitHub to see which style I like, however, I decided that if I have only 1 or 2interfaces to keep them with the logic, and for eg. the WS Interaction interfaces, since they were getting plenty I put them in a separate .ts file. Thank you so much for your help ^^ It's my first day on TS, kinda confusing coming from JS haha.